# How to include dynamically generated classes in package setup

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py, python-wheel

I generate ~200 classes dynamically using the `type()` constructor, that I would like to export. The gist of my setup.py is as follows

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup

# Create 200 classes
my_classes = []
for i in range(200):
   new_class = type(f'Class{str(i)}', (SomeParent, ), {})
   my_classes.append(new_class)

setup(
   name='my_package',
   version="0.0.1",
   ...
)
```

I would like to include these classes (somehow) in the setup, so that I can import these classes from the built `my_package` wheel:

```py
from my_package import Class58, Class107, Class189
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: At packaging time, you should only care about files. Classes (dynamically generated or not) do not matter. This loop creating classes, should probably be in a function in one of the actual Python file of the library instead (i.e. not in `setup.py`).

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc. What I'm really trying to achieve is editor peek/autocomplete, that is for the editor (consider the second code block) to recognise the unique attributes of a specific ClassXYZ imported from my_package. 

Of course the loop is badly placed in the setup.py, but putting it in another file will not solve the problem of exposing them to wherever my_package is being imported.